# Find and replace part of a string using bash in an XML file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am new to bash scripting and was looking into what kid of command will help me replace a specific string in an xml file.

The string looks like

```
uri='file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/r/c/e/v/1.1/abc-1.1.jar'
```

Should be replaced with

```
uri='file:/lib/abc-1.1.jar'
```

The strings vary as the jars vary too. First part of the string "file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/r/" is constant and is across all strings. The 2nd half is varying

This needs to be done across entire file. Please note that replacing one is easier then doing it for each an every string that varies. I am trying to look for solution to do it in one single command.

I know we can use sed but how? Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed "s~uri='file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/r/c/e/v/1\.1/abc-1.1.jar~uri='file:/lib/abc-1\.1\.jar'~g"
```

Basically it is:

```
sed "s~pattern~replacement~g"
```

where `s` is the command substitute and the trailing `g` means globally. I'm using `~` as the delimiter char as this helps to avoid escaping all that `/` in the paths. (thanks @Jotne)

---

Update: In order to make the regex more flexible, you may try this:

```
sed 's~file.*/\(.*\.jar\)\(.*\)~file:///lib/\1\2~' a.txt
```

It searches for `file: ... .jar` links, grabs the name of the jar file and builds the new links.

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl for the quick response! That was very quick. How can you do this repeatedly with first half of the string been static and second half keeps changing (as per question). I want to replace all strings in the file with similar format. 2nd string for example will look like uri='file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/t/e/s/t/v/1.9/zzz-1.9.jar' to be replace by 'uri='file:/lib/zzz-1.9.jar'

Comment: Try the following `sed -re "s~uri='file:\S+/(\S+)'$~uri='file:/lib/\1'~g" file`

Comment: @hek2mgl With nearly 23000 points here, you should know that `sed` can use different separator like this: `sed "s~uri='file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/r/c/e/v/1\.1/abc-1.1.jar~uri='file:/lib/abc-1\.1\.jar~g"` This way you do not need to escape all `/`

Comment: @Masti I have to leave for today. If you have patience until tomorrow I can help.. I guess the community might being faster.. :)

Comment: @Jotne I think text editing is a task for `sed`. Althought it is nicely possible with `awk`, `sed` should be used here. Or even `xslt` because regexes and `html/xml` aren't friends..... cu, and thanks for the `~` ... :)

Comment: I can wait :) While I will try above approaches and modify. If I find a solution then I surely will update this thread! Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F/ '/file:\/var\/lib\/abc\/cde.repo\/r/ {print $1,$3,$NF}' OFS=/ file
uri='file:/lib/abc-1.1.jar'
```

Static URL, but changing file name.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `sed` or even `awk`.  You could simply use `basename`:

```
prefix='file:/lib/'
uri='file:/var/lib/abc/cde.repo/r/c/e/v/1.1/abc-1.1.jar'
result="${prefix}$(basename ${uri})"
echo ${result}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
sudo sed -i -e "s/stringToChange/TheNewString/g" test.xml
```